# non-overrideing jaxb generation

Tags: eclipse, jaxb

I am trying to generate a bunch of xml annotated pojos.  To do this I have all my xsd files in the resource folder of my project (they are from the polycom rmx sdk, RmxSdkApiV7_8-EMA_EMA-V7_8_0_303).  I then right click on each one (over 150 of them) go to generate and click JAXB classes.  I pick the project and give it a namespace than finish the wizard.  After doing this there is a warning that any newly generated classes will override existing ones.  This is my problem, because some commonly used objects will have different definitions in different xsd files.  So when the override happens whatever was defined is lost.

So for example, response_trans_conf.xsd defines GET as

```
<xsd:element name="GET">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="CONFERENCE" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Where as another schema file like trans_conf_2.xsd defines GET as

```
<xsd:element name="GET">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="ID"/>
            <xsd:element ref="OBJ_TOKEN"/>
            <xsd:any processContents="skip" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="##other"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

So I'll end up with a Get object that looks like

```
public class GET {
    @XmlElement(name = "CONFERENCE")
    protected ConferenceContent conference;
```

OR (respectively)

```
public class GET {
    @XmlElement(name = "ID", required = true)
    protected BigInteger id;
    @XmlElement(name = "OBJ_TOKEN", required = true)
    protected String objtoken;
    @XmlAnyElement
    protected List<Element> any;
```

What I need is an object that a combination of both.  Like I said there are over 150 xsd files in this sdk.  So this problem is multiplied by few other common objects.
FYI at the same time of wanting a combined class rather then an overridden one Im hoping the solution would also prevent duplicates some how.

Comment: if the final output is the combination of all elements (avoiding duplicate), then I see one possibility is to change xsd to relate the common elements using  `xsd complextype extension` [link] (http://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_extension.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

due to lack of answers I have implemented a workaround which is to manually add the missing/needed members.

Im sure the comment above by ulab would work as well but I really do not want to edit the xsd's

The other option I see but did not implement is a wrapper.  extending these common classes to have all the members in another layer above the sdk's generated file.  that would ensure the sdk doesnt need to be touch even when there is a new version and a new generation of files.